# SQL Query Not Exists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

We have two systems that sell different types of items. We want to display customers with ONLY accounts in Sandbox1, compared to those in Sandbox2. I have used the WHERE NOT EXISTS, but I'm not sure it's working correctly. I get an error when I try to run it: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'MSTO15' to data type int. So I'm not sure what's causing that or if I'm on the right track with my query.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT [Account #], Accounts, [Prior Annual], [Prior Annual1], [Prior Annual2]
FROM Sandbox1.dbo.SalesHistory as s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Sandbox2.dbo.customer_master as m
     WHERE s.[Account #] = 
           m.customer_number)
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you want to achieve, please?

Comment: What's the datatypes of s.[Account #] and m.customer_number? Based on the error message one seems to be an INTEGER and the other a CHAR...

Comment: One is an int and the other is a varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [Account #], Accounts, [Prior Annual], [Prior Annual1], [Prior Annual2]
FROM Sandbox1.dbo.SalesHistory as s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Sandbox2.dbo.customer_master as m
     WHERE convert(nvarchar,s.[Account #]) = 
           convert(nvarchar,m.customer_number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT [Account #], Accounts, [Prior Annual], [Prior Annual1], [Prior Annual2]
FROM Sandbox1.dbo.SalesHistory as s
where s.[Account #] not in (select [Account #] from Sandbox2.customer_master)
```